# Error exception when calling foreach at controller page in laravel5

Tags: php, laravel-5

```
public function disUplds()
{
    $upldtbls=Upldtbl::all();
    $grades = DB::table('upldtbls')->pluck('grade');
    foreach ($grades as $grade) {

        echo $grade;
    }
    return view('viewUploads',compact('upldtbls'));
}
```

Above is the code which I want to retrieve all the data from the `grade` column of the `upldtbls` table. So `$grade` variable should contain that as an array. But following error occurs.

[image]

Comment: `var_dump($grades);` and check what is in it? Should be an array of `grade`s.

Comment: There should be 2 values. But only one value is printed for the var_dump($grades);

Answer (score 1):

Write your view line as below:-

```
return View::make('viewUploads')->with(compact('upldtbls'));
```

Also check object is set or not.

```
if(isset($grades) && !empty($grades)){
  foreach ($grades as $grade){
        echo $grade;
  }
}
```

OR

```
if(isset($grades) && count($grades) > 0){
  foreach ($grades as $grade){
        echo $grade;
  }
}
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: no it will not work. Invalid argument supplied for foreach() is the error

Comment: `isset($grades)` would always be `true` here.

Comment: That also not working and return the same error. $grades is not empty there. It should contain 2 values since table contains 2 rows.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
  public function disUplds()
{
    $upldtbls=Upldtbl::all();
    $grades = DB::table('upldtbls')->select('grade')->get();
    foreach ($grades as $grade) {

        echo $grade;
    }
    return view('viewUploads',compact('upldtbls'));
}
```